# X and dots added to column names when creating a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to create  a data.frame with column names specified. When I input the following:

```
df_ht <- data.frame("Teams" = NA, "Shots" = NA, "Shots On Target" = NA)
```

I get the following header:

```
              Teams Shots Shots.On.Target
1                NA    NA              NA
```

Then I put spaces next to the names to try spacing out the actual column names:

```
df_ht <- data.frame(" Teams " = NA, " Shots " = NA, " Shots On Target " = NA)
```

And I got this:

```
          X.Teams. X.Shots. X.Shots.On.Target.
1           NA            NA                 NA
```

Why did the `X` and the `.` appear? How can I get rid of the `.`?

Comment: Read the documentation at `?data.frame` and pay particular attention to the `check.names` argument. Follow any links provided there.

Comment: Found a solution at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3411201/specifying-column-names-in-a-data-frame-changes-spaces-to. Need to set check.names to False.

Comment: Indeed, just as it says in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

When you create a `data.frame`, by default it has the option `check.names = TRUE`. This mean R will check the names provided are syntactically valid names, and they are created using `make.names`.

From `?make.names`, a syntactically valid name:

> [..] consists of letters, numbers and the dot or underline characters
>   and starts with a letter or the dot not followed by a number. Names
>   such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the reserved words.

Also, the invalid characters are replaced by dots.

If you do

```
df_ht <- data.frame(" Teams " = NA, " Shots " = NA,
                    " Shots On Target " = NA, check.names=FALSE)
```

you will get what you want, but this is not recommended at all. You will have a lot of complications to call or use the variables inside your data.frame (like need to use back ticks around the column/variable name or lost the autocompletion features). The purpose of the column names are to use them like in `df_ht$Teams` and are able to manipulate them, not to look well when printed.

Comment: Good point on giving column names so they are easy to manipulate afterwards. But note that using back ticks ` is a way to get around that.

Comment: @Dombey, that's the complication I was talking about.